# How to get the application version programmatically in Compose Desktop?

Tags: compose-desktop

I know it's possible to set the version in `build.gradle` → `nativeDistributions.packageVersion` ...
but how does one read that version in the source code of the app, for example to print it in the `application` composable?

On macOs the about screen is available when opening the distributable app, and it shows the version we set via `build.gradle`:
[image]

Comment: As a workaround, for now I'm providing an argument to the `nativeDistributions` with `args += listOf("-v=${rootProject.version}",)` and using that in release builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the following, which will return the package version as String:

```
System.getProperty("jpackage.app-version")
```

**Note:** You should run your application using `gradle runDistributable`, otherwise the `"jpackage.app-version"` property will be *null*.